# How can I extract a list of files with download counts from an Apache log

Tags: apache, logging, grep

Good day! I have a standard Apache log file, and I'd like to be able to extract a list of downloaded .m4a files in a specific directory, along with a count of how many times each was downloaded. I know how to do this for a single file, with:

```
grep filename.txt logfile | grep " 200" | wc -l
```

But that just gives me a single number, and I need to know each file name ahead of time.

What I'd like to get out is a sorted list of download counts and file names something along these lines:

```
650 /podcasts/12323.m4a
623 /podcasts/12329.m4a
601 /podcasts/12329.m4a
432 /podcasts/11521.m4a
```

And so on... Thanks!

cheers... -Adam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
cat access.log | awk '$9==200 { print $7 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

(where the file name is in the 7th and 200 in the 9th  position of the log file)

Comment: That was great for putting me on the right track, thanks! I needed to extract just the log lines that had the m4a files in them, so I changed it to:

`grep -E "podcasts\/[0-9]+\.m4a" access_log.1391040000 | awk '{ print $8 }' | sort | uniq -c`

What it still doesn't do is sort by the number of the downloads, instead of the filename. That's relatively minor, but would still be nice to figure out.

Comment: Yes, this counts all files.